# python best practice, combining core application with rest service calls

Tags: python, rest, api

I have a question about coding best practice. I am developing an application with heavy computation that is continuously working on many objects in parallel.

at the end of each object life cycle through the pipeline, i want to json parse this object and post it through a restful service call.

should i save those objects locally and have a separate simple application to take care of posting those objects through the restful service or should i integrate calling the service through creating a new thread in my main application?

i want to know what is the best practice in terms of robustness and code cleanness.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to give a general answer for this question. In term of robustness and code cleanness it is important to observe the principle of separation of concerns.

That means that the part that produces the object must be independant of the part that posts it: they should be separately tested, and only communicate through a well defined interface.

But the interface can be as loose as a different process and a disk spool, or as tight as another thread in the same application recieving a Python object. Only the context (from the developper proficiency to the deployment concern and eventually containing performance questions) may give elements to chose.